# Dynamically modify GraphQL schema and see updated schema with GraphiQL

Tags: java, graphiql, graphql-schema, spring-graphql

I have a GraphQL schema:

```
enum CustomType {
  Foo
  Bar
}
```

But I need to add enum items from my database. For that, I have made a Visitor that modify the schema model during runtime:

```java
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
class GraphQlConfig {

    @Bean
    public GraphQlSourceBuilderCustomizer sourceBuilderCustomizer() {
        return builder -> builder.typeVisitors(List.of(new AssetGraphQlVisitor()));
    }
}
```

```java
public class AssetGraphQlVisitor extends GraphQLTypeVisitorStub {

    @Override
    public TraversalControl visitGraphQLEnumType(GraphQLEnumType node, TraverserContext<GraphQLSchemaElement> context) {
        GraphQLEnumType returnedNode = node;
        if (node.getName().equals("CustomType")) {
            returnedNode = returnedNode
                    .transform(builder -> CustomType.getAll().forEach(type -> builder.value(type.getName())));
        }
        return super.visitGraphQLEnumType(returnedNode, context);
    }
}
```

This seems to work well but when I go to my GraphiQL web interface, my custom types aren't present in the displayed schema...

How can I update the schema used by GraphiQL received from Spring GraphQL ?

Thanks!